# Modify Custom Post Type Slug

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have a CPT called 'projects', which display images with their titles.
I have a page to display the CPT's called 'single-projects.php'.

Is there a way through using templates and/or functions, to display the slugs like this:

- themename/projects/project/
  This is so I can show all the CPT's in that project list on the single-project page.

instead of

- themename/projects/slug-of-post
  This doesn't make sense to have each unique post slug if I am just showing one page for all CPT's in that list. I tried the rewrite argument, but I only want to change the slug-of-post.

I know I can change the slug for each CPT in their dashboard, but I want to do it via the back-end.

In my front-page I tried to use echo site_url('/single-project') for the image links but that doesn't work, am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: I don't really get the question. Are you showing your posts on the single post pages; they're supposed to show just one post. And are you aware that you can enable archives for the post type, with custom URL like `example.com/my-archive`? And you can use the `archive-<post type>.php` template to customize the archive display?

Comment: I did initially have a single-page for my cpt's, but I changed it to a page template instead, so i can show all projects in a specific group, and the url will just be 'sitename/project/', which is what I wanted. I also have set has-archive for my cpt, to show every project group I create too. I am just learning at the moment too.

Comment: So, do you still need help with the slug in question? If so, can you clarify the question - show what you've tried and the expected outcome?

Comment: My previous reply answers this question. Thanks.